# Check if list of objects contains an object with a certain attribute value in django template tags

Tags: python, django

I want to check if my list of objects contains an object with a certain attribute value in Django template tags. As we know it is represented in Python like:

```py
any(x.name == "t2" for x in l)
```

So, is there some tags to express this in template tags something like:

```
{% if any x.atype == "Other" for x in list %}
{% endif %}
```

or something else do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in tag for this, but you can create your own: add `templatetags` python directory to your project app where you plan to use tag. Then add file called `tags.py` and insert code listed below (example):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name=any)
def any_of_following(objects, value):
    return any([item for item in objects if item == value])
```

Then you can use this tag in template as following:

```
{% any your_objects value_to_check %}
```

You can read more about simple_tags in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag)